# how to transform a Data Frame, shifting a new index_col and a new index_row?

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
state           demvot      year         

Alabama          84         1932
Arizona          67         1932
Arkansas         86         1932
California       58         1932
*********************************
Alabama          63         1936
Arizona          51         1936
Arkansas         39         1936
California       55         1936
```

I want to set an index_col assinged as 'year' grouped by year (1932,1936,1940) and an index_row assigned as 'state', grouped by state (Alabama, Arakansas...) and inside the demVote.

An example as follows:

```
    state Alabama Arizona Arkansas California
year                  
1932      84       67      86        58
1936      70       35      ...
1940
1944
```

The programming language to be used must be r.

Comment: Please search this site (or the web) for `long format`and `wide format` and find tools like `reshape2` packages, `cast` and `melt` functions and many more approaches. Also please read about examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve